# Replacement of OpenLayers.Control.NavigationHistory in OpenLayers 3

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3

Is there any replacement of [`OpenLayers.Control.NavigationHistory`](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.13.1/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Control/NavigationHistory-js.html) (OpenLayers 2) in OpenLayers 3? I did not find any example in the [OpenLayers 3 Examples](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.5.0/examples/) page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment, you need to manage navigation history in your browser at  application level. There are not dedicated component for this purpose. I clearly don't know if the library will include later a component.

You will see that [the permalink example](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.5.0/examples/permalink.html) illustrates a way to manage history using the [`window.history` component](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history).

You may need to use a third party library to "shim" the `window.history` API in browsers that do not support it. It can be https://github.com/devote/HTML5-History-API

A "shim" is like a backport of functions available in recent browsers but for old browsers versions through JavaScript code.